# "shell not found" error in gitlab deployment for k8s

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, bitnami

Trying to run gitlab pipeline for k8s and getting the following error:

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Using docker image sha256:a1216024d119dbf6b3a6e731d47f08a36de468de70e8 for bitnami/kubectl:latest with digest bitnami/kubectl@sha256:c74b703deed247e544a3feca13be7ecb0b091e4d2c3b825c8 ...
shell not found
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This is the relevant portion of the `.gitlab.yaml`:

```
qa-release:
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: release
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  environment:
    name: dev
  tags:
    - <removed>
  script:
    - echo "Deploying Kube Manifests to SERVER"
    <rest .... removed...>

  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`bitnami/kubectl:latest` image does not come with sh / bash shells. it is very light weight container image.

things under `script` trying to execute inside the container, and it is not getting any executable shell.

Try to find or build your own container image which has kubectl and bash / sh both available.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the description is not clear but I would suggest that there is no issue with the bitnami/kubectl:latest image because when I am running in the docker it is able to get into the shell by interactive mode. So the bitnami/kubectl:latest image is comes with the shell.

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash bitnami/kubectl:latest
```

I would suggest you to check the gitlab runners having any issue.